# El botón de "ignorar etiqueta" sale de su contenedor

Tags: bug, diseño

El nuevo diseño del *tooltip*, sobre la información de etiqueta, no se adapta al ancho de sus botones, específicamente el botón de *ignorar etiqueta*

[image: Tooltip con etiqueta monitoreada]

[image: Tooltip con etiqueta no monitoreada]

Lo probé en:

- Firefox 61.0.1 (64-bits)
- Safari 11.1.2 (13605.3.8)
- Google Chrome 68.0.3440.75 (Build oficial) (64 bits)

Todos en el sistema operativo macOS.

---

**Actualización**

Gracias a la [excelente idea](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3587/22721) de [Pikoh](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/15301/pikoh), el problema se ha resuelto, cuando no estamos siguiendo una etiqueta

[image: Problema resuelto]

Pero el problema todavía persiste si vemos una etiqueta que estamos siguiendo

[image: Problema no resuelto]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yo también observo el mismo comportamiento. El problema creo que es el siguiente: En inglés esos textos son *Watch Tag* y *Ignore Tag*. Como ves,son textos mucho mas cortos. Propongo modificar la traducción de *Monitorear Etiqueta* por *Seguir etiqueta*, lo que creo que hará que los botones quepan en su sitio.

He usado [traducir.win](https://traducir.win/) y he añadido esta propuesta como sugerencia de traducción y las he marcado como urgentes. Espero que en breve sean aprobadas y podamos ver si se soluciona el problema de esa manera.

**Editado.**

Ya que al seguir una etiqueta todavía se sale un poco el botón, propongo sustituir "No seguir etiqueta" por "Dejar de seguir". Si nadie dice nada en contra, haré la sugerencia de traducción en [traducir.win](https://traducir.win)

Comment: ¡Buena iniciativa! Pensé que podía aprobar sugerencias y así iba a hacerlo, pero ahora mismo [no veo cómo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfMZ0.png).

Comment: @fedorqui al ser yo un "trusted user" imagino que ya estan "aprobadas", y que solo falta la aprobación final de g3rv4, pero supongo que el sabrá mejor si es asi :)

Comment: Pensaba que iba diferente: nosotros podemos aprobarlas, pero solamente aparecen en la web cuando g3rv4 o Juan hacen un pull. Bueno, esperemos a que Latinoamérica se levante y nos saque de dudas :P

Comment: @fedorqui en un rato salimos de dudas,efectivamente :)

Comment: @fedorqui es correcto lo que dice Pikoh... los trusted users (ustedes) pueden hacer ya cadenas "aprobadas". El próximo paso es que un reviewer (un mod) les de el OK en traducir. Con eso el sistema hace push a transifex. Después hace falta que un CM importe las cadenas de Transifex a la base de datos. Yo hice los dos últimos pasos, así que vamos a ver los cambios en el próximo build.

Comment: @g3rv4 perfecto, gracias. Me resultaba confuso que "approved by" saliera en blanco, cuando a efectos prácticos ya estaba aprobada (sugerencia: añadir algo así como "automatically approved by trusted user").

Comment: ¡Excelente! Veo que también se cambiaron las demás traducciones que hacían referencia a la palabra _monitorear_ :)

Comment: Mejoró muchísimo, pero todavía hay un problema cuando se sigue una etiqueta. Si como comunidad se decide que no molesta mucho, puedo marcar la respuesta como aceptada :)

Comment: @KacosPro cierto, al seguirla luego el texto es _No seguir etiqueta_, lo suficientemente largo para que el texto de la derecha (_Ignorar etiqueta_) se salga un poco por la derecha.

Comment: @fedorqui si, lo imaginaba, pero no encontré un sinónimo más corto para ese texto (_Unwatch tag_)

Comment: @fedorqui que te parece "dejar de seguir"? Es más corto, y creo que el sentido es similar

Comment: @Pikoh suena bien, la palabra _etiqueta_ puede omitirse (También podemos aprovechar que todos somos programadores, utilizar `!` para negar y dejarlo en un simple _! seguir_ :P)

Comment: @fedorqui buena propuesta XD! lo que pasa es que no en todos los lenguajes se usa `!` como negación ;)

Comment: Pensé exactamente lo mismo, ya que nos encontramos en el contexto de _etiqueta_ para mí, _seguir_ y _dejar de seguir_ serían suficientes.

Comment: @Pikoh He actualizado las traducciones.  Sigan sugiriendo y cambiando las necesarias y las aprobaré yo.