# Desbordamiento del botón "Ignorar etiqueta" en tooltip de información de etiqueta

Tags: bug, estado-completado

Si bien podría ser un duplicado de [El botón de "ignorar etiqueta" sale de su contenedor](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3586/el-bot%C3%B3n-de-ignorar-etiqueta-sale-de-su-contenedor/), esta vez la cuestión se produce con el botón *Dejar de seguir etiqueta*.

Pasos para reproducir el problema:

1. Posicionar el puntero del mouse sobre una etiqueta seguida.
2. Se visualiza lo siguiente:

[image: Botón "dejar de seguir etiqueta" extenso]

Navegadores testeados:

- Firefox 86.0
- Brave 1.20.103

En aquel entonces, Pikoh había sugerido en su [respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3587/156327) traducir el texto del botón como *Dejar de seguir*. ¿Cómo proceder entonces, ya que el caso es prácticamente idéntico?

Comment: Debieras haber dicho el botón **dejar de seguir etiqueta** expulsa al botón **ignorar etiqueta** del contenedor ...

Comment: Lo considero bien. De hecho, ambos términos son correctos en este contexto. Lo que si pueden hacer es que el contenedor `.js-embedded-tag-preferences` que es donde se encuentran los botones se vuelva en un contenedor de cajas flexibles, donde los botones que están contenidos en él sean las _cajas flexibles_ o tratadas como tal para que se ajuste al ancho disponible.

Comment: Es una posibilidad, pero puede cambiarse la estructura HTML también para hacerla más manejable.

Comment: En aquella ocasión modificar las traducciones solventaba el problema dado que al hacer mas cortas las traducciones se conseguía evitar el overflow. Pero como vemos, no se soluciona el problema subyacente, y es que el contenedor no se adapta correctamente a la longitud de los botones. Considero que lo mejor es reportarlo para que se revise desde arriba a ver si pueden solucionarlo. Voy a añadir la etiqueta para escalarlo.

Comment: Adding this to be addressed as part of our regular bug duty rotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We made the tooltip wider, so it should accommodate the button text in all languages. Thanks for the report!

[image]